# How to count duplicates and output variable of origin

Tags: r, count, duplicates

I have 12 variables in R of varying lengths. They each contain a list of amino acids. I have merged them into a dataframe using cbind() and I would like to output the number of times each sequence is duplicated and in which variable the duplicate is found. I have successfully used the table() function to output the number of times the sequence is duplicated but I can't find a way to determine where the duplicates arise.

Here is an example of the data:

```
S1 <- c("CVVSTNGGSGTYKYIF", "CVVSLKF_GYALNF", "CAVNTQCSPDTCSLYPNLPCPRNA*CRAGVQT_VLFRSVWRV*NDGFCNDLEHCVSNFGNEKLTF")

S2 <- c("CVVSTNGGSGTYKYIF", "CVVSLKF_GYALNF", "CAVNTQCSPDTCSLYPNLPCPRNA*CRAGVQT_VLFRSVWRV*NDGFCNDLEHCVSNFGNEKLTF", "CAAGYGKLTF", "CVVL_ALMF")

S3 <- c("CAVNTQCSPDTCSLYPNLPCPRNA*CRAGVQT_VLFRSVWRV*NDGFCNDLEHCVSNFGNEKLTF", "CAAGYGKLTF", "CVVL_ALMF")

n <- max(length(S1), length(S2), length(S3))
length(S1) <- n
length(S2) <- n
length(S3) <- n

clones <- cbind(S1, S2, S3)

freq <- as.data.frame(table(clones))
freq
```

This outputs:

| Clones | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| CAAGYGKLTF | 2 |
| CAVNTQCSPDTCSLYPNLPCPRNA*CRAGVQT_VLFRSVWRV*NDGFCNDLEHCVSNFGNEKLTF | 3 |
| CVVL_ALMF | 2 |
| CVVSLKF_GYALNF | 2 |
| CVVSTNGGSGTYKYIF | 2 |

But what I want as the output is:

| Clones | Freq | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAAGYGKLTF | 2 | S2,S3 |
| CAVNTQCSPDTCSLYPNLPCPRNA*CRAGVQT_VLFRSVWRV*NDGFCNDLEHCVSNFGNEKLTF | 3 | S1,S2,S3 |
| CVVL_ALMF | 2 | S2,S3 |
| CVVSLKF_GYALNF | 2 | S1,S2 |
| CVVSTNGGSGTYKYIF | 2 | S1,S2 |

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
vars <- c("S1", "S2", "S3") # Create a vector with the names of the variables for each vector of amino acid sequences

# For each vector of amino acid sequences, create a dataframe where the second column is
# the vector of amino acid sequences, and the first column is the name of the variable
# where the sequence is stored
dfs <- lapply(vars , function(x) as.data.frame(cbind(x, get(x)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

# Combine all the dataframe created in the previous step, into a single dataframe
combined_df <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
# Name the columns of the dataframe
names(combined_df) <- c("Variable", "Sequence")

library(dplyr)

combined_df %>% 
    group_by(Sequence) %>% 
    summarise(Freq = n(), Variable = paste(Variable, collapse = ",")) %>% 
    arrange(Sequence)
```

Comment: Hey Akindele, THANKS SO MUCH for this! It is exactly what I needed. I knew I was just going down the wrong rabbit hole.